# fancybox, change media parameters for youtube

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I have the following code to display a fancybox window to display a youtube video.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox({
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        helpers: {
            media: {
                youtube: {
                    params: {
                        autoplay: 1,
                        rel: 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I want to replace video parameters, such as `rel`, with HTML5 Custom Data Attributes (`data-*`) of the pressed link. You can see an example in:

http://jsfiddle.net/poselab/LrvR8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could fetch the value of the `data-fancybox-rel` attribute (as in your example) using the `beforeLoad` callback like :

```
beforeLoad: function () {
    dataRel = $(this.element).data("fancybox-rel");
}
```

... assuming that you have declared `dataRel` globally.

Then pass it as a returning parameter withing the `rel` option of the media helper like :

```
rel: function () {
     return dataRel;
}
```

See forked **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/VwTpp/)**